# What is skweness attack on l-diversity?

Tags: security, privacy

What is skewness attack on l-diversity exactly mean? I can't find any information or resource for this answer. As far as I could find on the web, it is about percentage of Sensitive attributes but I don't get what is the thing. Does anybody with privacy and security background know the answer to this? Thank you.